# What system information is useful in an emergency?

Tags: command-line, hardware, restore

I want to store a text file on Ubuntu One containing command-line output in case of a system fault that stops me logging in or seeing my screen. That way I can retrieve the information on my phone if I need to ask for help on here from another system. I got the idea after seeing some questions on here about major faults that had some responders asking for more information such as Ubuntu version, graphics card, what devices were connected and so on. It occurred to me that I wouldn't be able to answer those questions if I couldn't access my system because I'm not really a hardware guy and don't retain that kind of information very well in my memory. So my question is:

If I were to ask about a serious problem, such as no screen or can't log in at all, what command outputs would be most useful for you to see in order to help with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that stops you from logging in (even to the console) or seeing your screen is most probably a hardware problem. Hardware is also less likely to change between when you save the information and when you need it, which makes it more useful to troubleshoot than software configuration files which can change often.

The two hardware info outputs I recommend storing are:

1. `sudo lshw > ~/lshw-output-20120612.txt`
2. `sudo lspci -v > ~/lspciv-output-20120612.txt`